# Implementation of observer pattern for Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, observer-pattern

I wrote an implementation of observer pattern as part of my [online battle Chess game](https://battlechess.herokuapp.com/):

```
const observers = Symbol();

class Observer{

    constructor(){

        if(new.target === Observer){

            throw new Error('Cannot create new Observer object. Observer is supposed to be inherited only.');
        }

        /**
         * @private
         * @type {Set}
         */
        this[observers] = new Set();
    }

    on(observer, event, callback){

        this.getObservers().add({

            observer,
            event,
            callback
        });
    }

    off(observer, event){

        const observers = this.getObservers();
        const observerEntries = this.getObservers().values();

        for(let entry of observerEntries){

            if(entry.observer === observer && entry.event === event){

                observers.delete(entry);
            }
        }
    }

    notify(event, data = {}){

        const observerEntries = this.getObservers().values();

        for(let entry of observerEntries){

            if(entry.event === event){

                entry.callback.call(entry.observer, data);
            }
        }
    }

    getObservers(){

        return this[observers];
    }
}

module.exports = Observer;
```

The source code for the full game is in a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Furmanus/Chess-online/tree/c01d4b784c5f48338bda1b7650669cf0fcb4fea1). This is an early version, without many features implemented and possibly with many bugs. I have a humble request to review my code. I'm aware of several things (backend Node code is very messy). The client-side is written in MVC and Observer patterns. I'm looking for feedback (both positive and negative) and advice/guidelines.

Comment: Question edited, though in case of rather larger projects I don't see any point in posting single short examples of code.

Comment: This is outside the scope of this Code Review question, but your login page code crashes [here](https://github.com/Furmanus/Chess-online/blob/c01d4b784c5f48338bda1b7650669cf0fcb4fea1/client/scripts/login/login_page.js#L27) because `input[type=text` is malformed.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the `Observer` class is confusing: an `Observer` contains `observers`?  I think that the class would make more sense if you renamed it `Observable`.

For the `.on()` and `.off()` methods, I think that the `event` parameter should come first.  That would mimic the natural English expression: "on *event* tell *observer* to do *action*".  It's also how it's done in other frameworks like [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

I'm mildly annoyed by the excessive vertical spacing of the code.